# Django, subset of foreign key

Tags: python, mysql, django

I need a way to select a subset of a foreign key, but only limit it to a subset. This is the raw query that was used in the old PHP database;

```
SELECT a.name FROM character_trait b
LEFT JOIN trait a ON b.id_trait = a.id
WHERE b.id_character = 1
AND a.id_traittype = 10
```

All the tables, character, trait, traittype and character_trait are available, but I can't figure out how to do it in Djando. My idea was this;

```
traits = CharacterTrait.objects.filter( id_character = character, id_trait.id_traittype = 10 )
```

But that just gives an error "keyword can't be an expression". I can do it in a very ugly way and just iterate through the resulting 'traits' using a for loop like this;

```
traits = CharacterTrait.objects.filter( id_character = character )  

for t in traits:
    print t.id_trait.id_traittype.id

    if t.id_trait.id_traittype.id == 10:
        print "Got One"
```

Edit, the module definitions;

```
class Trait(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField? 
    id_traittype = models.ForeignKey(Traittype, null=True, db_column = 'id_traittype')

    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'trait'

    def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name

class Traittype(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'traittype'

    def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name    

class Trait(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField? 
    id_traittype = models.ForeignKey(Traittype, null=True, db_column = 'id_traittype')

    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'trait'

    def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name

class CharacterTrait(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    ##id_character = models.IntegerField()
    ## id_trait = models.IntegerField()
    id_character = models.ForeignKey(Werewolfcharacter, null=True, db_column = 'id_character')
    id_trait     = models.ForeignKey(Trait,             null=True, db_column = 'id_trait')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'character_trait'

    def __unicode__(self):
                return self.id_trait.name
```

Comment: could you post your model definitions? django filter keywoards use `__` 2 under scores to span fk relationships

Comment: Done, added modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to suggest you needed to chain the filters, like

```
traits = CharacterTrait.objects.filter( id_character = character).filter(id_trait__id_traittype = 10 )
```

But looking back at some code,

```
traits = CharacterTrait.objects.filter( id_character = character, id_trait__id_traittype = 10 )
```

Should be sufficient, where the key thing is replacing the . with __ as suggested by dm03514

Answer (score 0):

One simple possibilty, since you (presumably) already have the correct SQL in your PHP code, is simply to [use raw SQL queries in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/).

Answer (score 0):

You should read the docs on [lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships). You need to use the double-underscore syntax:

```
CharacterTrait.objects.filter(id_character=character, id_trait__id_traittype=10)
```